# How to present my semantic search model results in minibuffer to select them and open file?

Tags: org-mode, doom, ripgrep

I have an org-roam directory where I keep all my notes in org files. Currently to search through my notes, I use keyword searching using `ripgrep` with `rg.el`. With this method, `rg` pops up the results in the minibuffer and I can cycle through them and select one of the items to open the file.

I recently moved towards building a semantic search model in Python and it takes my keywords as inputs and outputs the filename and relevant text in the file. I wanted to to present the output the same way `rg.el` presents it in the minibuffer in Eemacs. I was wondering how I can do this or what direction to look towards since I have not built any custom Elisp programs before?

Comment: https://emacs.stackexchange.com/tags/elisp/info

Comment: You should use `completing-read` probably with `process-lines`. Might you have a question about how to use it, then please add an example of the output from your python file to the question (not in a comment). Thanks